# How to throw while using a CryptoStream without causing a CryptoGraphicException

Tags: c#, io, cryptography, cryptostream

I'm reading an encrypted file and want to throw a specific error whenever the password is incorrect. Since decrypting with an incorrect password would simply succeed but return gibberish data, I'd like to determine if the password is correct.

The way I do this is I write a "magic value" to the encrypted file; let's say I write the value `MaGiC` to the file. Whenever I'm decrypting the file I ensure the first 5 bytes contain `MaGiC`. If not, the password used to decrypt the file must be wrong and so I throw an `InvalidPasswordException`.

```
MAGICHEADER = new byte[] { 0x4D, 0x61, 0x47, 0x69, 0x43 };      // "MaGiC"

using (var fs = File.OpenRead(path))
using (var algo = ...)
using (var cs = new CryptoStream(fs, algo.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
{
    var hdr = new byte[MAGICHEADER.Length]; // Buffer
    cryptoStream.Read(hdr, 0, hdr.Length);  // Read magic header from encrypted stream

    // If the decrypted data doesn't equal the magic header this means the password is wrong
    if (!MAGICHEADER.SequenceEqual(hdr))
        throw new InvalidPasswordException();

    // ... read rest of file
}
```

For brevity I've left out a lot of stuff (which algorithm, key, IV, blocksize, padding, mode etc.). For this particular case, what may be important: I'm using `PKCS7` for padding (but I'm quite sure all padding will cause the described issue).

Now, on the calling side I wrote code like:

```
try {
    var data = ReadFile("C:\foo\bar", "INCORRECTPASSWORD");
    // ... Do stuff with data
} catch (InvalidPasswordException) {
    // Oh noes! Wrong password! Ask to enter password again
}
```

However, to my surprise the `InvalidPasswordException` was not caught; I **did** get an exception but of type `CryptographicException`: *Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.*.

When I debug the issue I see the `InvalidPasswordException` being thrown. **I also think I know what's going on**: the `InvalidPasswordException` is thrown, the `using` causes the `CryptoStream` to be disposed and the `CryptoStream` determines that since we're not at the end of the stream what is left must be "padding" which then causes an exception. Or at least something along those lines.

To 'force' MY exception getting thrown I could do something like:

```
if (!MAGICHEADER.SequenceEqual(hdr)) {
    try { cs.FlushFinalBlock(); } catch { }  // YUK!!
    throw new InvalidPasswordException();
}
```

Or:

```
if (!MAGICHEADER.SequenceEqual(hdr)) {
    try { cs.Dispose(); } catch { }  // YUK!!
    throw new InvalidPasswordException();
}
```

I was, however, hoping for a more elegant solution. Is there a way I can initialize the `CryptoStream` not to throw on disposal? Or a way to 'close' the `CryptoStream` cleanly without it throwing? I've tried `Close()`, `Clear()` etc. but all of these methods also cause the `CryptoGraphicException` forcing me to wrap them in a `try { ... } catch { ... }` just before throwing my own `InvalidPasswordException`.

Comment: Rather than a magic cookie why not prefix with a strong hash of the password? - then you can easily test without needing to begin decryption with an invalid password.  Having a known fixed constant value at the start of all ciphertext may also have security implications.

Comment: I'd rather not have any information related to the password stored in the file (even if used with a strong hash) since the file contains sensitive information which may be stored for decades and who knows when a flaw in "strong hash X" is found. The "magic cookie" (as you call it) is also not at the beginning of the file (nor at a fixed position); it's described it as such just to keep it simple(r). The file is bigger and has some ("random length") data before the "magic cookie".

Comment: Hmm, considering using @AlexK.'s suggestion anyway (storing a strong hash of the password in the 'unencrypted header' of the file). But that still leaves the question: how would I throw **anything** from that part of the code if all I'll ever get is a `CryptoGraphicException` at the callsite?

Comment: You could do away with the `using` part and perform the resource handling yourself. In the end using `using` is candy for the developer, but it isn't *required* for anything.